# MultiValueDictKeyError / request.POST

Tags: python, django

I think I hav a problem at *request.POST['title']*

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /blog/add/post/
>     "'title'"
>         Request Method:   GET
>         Request URL:  http://119.81.247.69:8000/blog/add/post/
>         Django Version:   1.8.2
>         Exception Type:   MultiValueDictKeyError
>         Exception Value:
>             "'title'"
>         Exception Location:   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-             packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in **getitem**, line 322
>         Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python
>         Python Version:   2.7.3

**views.py**

```
def add_post(request):
    entry_title = request.POST["title"]
    return HttpResponse('Hello %s' % entry_title)
```

**write.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="/blog/add/post/">
<p>
    <label for "title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for 'category'>Category</label>
    <select id="category" name="category"></select>
</p>
<p>
    <label for 'tags'>Tags</label>
    <input type="text" id="tags" value="" />
</p>
<p>
    <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Write" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change:

```
def add_post(request):
    entry_title = request.POST["title"]
    return HttpResponse('Hello %s' % entry_title)
```

to:

```
def add_post(request):
    entry_title = request.POST.get("title", "Guest (or whatever)")
    return HttpResponse('Hello %s' % entry_title)
```

and it won't throw a `KeyError`, but you should look at using Django's forms rather than pulling values directly from the POST data.

Alternatively, you can keep your existing code and simply check for the exception:

```
def add_post(request):
    try:
        entry_title = request.POST["title"]
    except KeyError:
        entry_title = "Guest"
    return HttpResponse('Hello %s' % entry_title)
```

but this is what `.get()` does internally already.

Comment: `request.POST` is a dictionary. Dictionaries in Python have a static method, `.get()` built-in. When `.get()` can't find the key you're looking for, it will return `None` by default, or the value you specify. In this case, I returned `"Guest (or whatever)"` as the default instead of `None`

Comment: @alTus How so? It's a perfectly valid way of getting the value from `request.POST` if it exists or return another value if it doesn't. How would you handle it? I'm not sure how much more succinct you can be than using `.get()` which perform the same `KeyError` exception handling internally.

Comment: Using `get` is ok, I just meant that author has some problems with sending form via post method and thus his title will always be empty (default).

Comment: He/she really needs to be using a Form or ModelForm for proper validation, etc. it's not clear given the current example code what fields are required.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I discovered that I forgot to add `"name=" text" "` in my `input type` in my Html page..

Answer (score 0):

As your traceback says: `Request Method: GET`.
So your POST dict is obviously empty and thus you get your `KeyError`.

Comment: but I tried to use POST method.

 That's why i wrote request.POST['title']
and
method="POST"

Comment: Well, I don't know any details but this request has `GET` method. `POST` is activated only with form submission.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing Files in POST method this could be because you might have missed encrypting the files in form tag of the HTML file i.e.-

```
{form action="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"}
                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

is required to avoid MultiValueDictError.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,but when i changed return HttpResponseRedirect('') 
to

return HttpResponseRedirect('/') 
it worked

Answer (score -1):

In Django project, I was facing the same problem, I did a mistake in url.py

***wrong***

```
path('support/',views.**support**,name='support'),

path('verifyDB/',views.**support**,name='verifyDB'),
```

***correct one***

```
path('support/',views.**support**,name='support'),

path('verifyDB/',views.**verifyDB**,name='verifyDB'),
```

so, check your path in view.py maybe there is a mistake.