# django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError DJANGO

Tags: ajax, django, input, multipartform-data

I have a form. When I post the form without using ajax, it works well. But when I use the ajax, I have an error like this;

```
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError:
```

My codes are below that without using ajax. It works.
HTML Form:

```
<form id="add_form" action="/adding/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="title">
   <input type="file" name="picture">
   <button type="submit" id="send_form" value="ok">Ok</button>
</form>
```

My views.py codes are:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    title = request.POST.get('title')
    pic = request.FILES['picture']
    query = Images_Table(title=title, pic=pic)
    query.save()
```

My model codes are:

```
class Images_Table(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
     pic = models.FileField(upload_to='images_folder', blank=True, null=True)
```

Until here; everythings are normal, codes works. When I use ajax, I have an error. My HTML Form:

```
<form id="add_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="file" name="picture">
    <button id="send_form" value="ok">Ok</button>
</form>
```

My ajax codes are:

```
$("#send_form").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
     url: '/adding/',
     method:'post',
     data: $("#add_form").serialize(),
     headers: '{{ csrf_token }}',
     success : function(){
         alert('Success posted!');
     }
  });
});
```

Error code is below;

```
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'picture'"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30696103/3254405

Comment: My codes are works, if I do not use ajax. When I use ajax, this problem appear.

Comment: Can you check raw headers and parameters sent with Fiddler as it may explain the issue..

Comment: looks like your AJAX request is posting a multi-valued field for the 'picture' file. Best is to check the raw post sent using a browser plugin. But it looks like your request.FILES is a MultiValueDict, in which case `pics = request.FILES.getlist('picture')` will give you list of files (with probably just one file in the list). You can handle both cases by checking `isinstance(request.FILES, MultiValueDict)` before doing the `getlist`.

Comment: I tried getlist(), I have no error but picture could not save to database. In database table shows "[ ]".

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing ajax.

```
$("#send_form").click(function(){
   var file_data = $('#picture').prop('files')[0];
   var form_data = new FormData($('form').get(0));
   form_data.append('file', file_data);
   $.ajax({
     url: '/adding/',
     method:'post',
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     data: form_data,
     headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
     success : function(){
       alert('Success posted!');
     }
   });
});
```